# jQuery shows JSON result in browser but does not show result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that gives geolocation of an IP address:

```js
// set endpoint and your access key
var ip = '134.201.250.155';
var access_key = '771d15ae7a7e93262786cc48009bac80';
console.log('http://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key);
// get the API result via jQuery.ajax
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        console.log(json);
 
        // output the "capital" object inside "location"
        console.log(json.location.capital); 

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The URL is: `http://api.ipstack.com/134.201.250.155?access_key=771d15ae7a7e93262786cc48009bac80`

It runs fine in browser and gives output in JSON format. But the alert does not execute in the code. I don't know why.

Please note that the service is free and the access_key is free for all, so there is no security concern.

Note: I gave up and used another service: https://ipapi.co/json/ This URL is working fine and giving me correct result in both console and code. Thanks guys for all your support.

Comment: That's what error handlers are for. You can also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for status, response data etc. That url doesn't appear to serve jsonp which is what you are requesting

Comment: I converted to a snippet - next time (and always), **check the console**.  It gives error `Cannot read property 'capital' of undefined` which means it *is* hitting the `success:` and the "alert" (changed to console.log for snippet) *is* being executed.   But the api is returning `success:false` which you need to check for in your code.

Comment: I gave up and used another service: https://ipapi.co/json/ This URL is working fine and giving me correct result in both console and code. Thanks guys for all your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use https api.ipstack endpoint because your site is https and [browser security](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content) does not allow you to use http calls on https websites.

I tried https call to ipstack  but your subscription does not support it.

You have to [pay](https://ipstack.com/product) for it.

Comment: I copied  and pasted the code but it didn't work. Any other URL like https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=? is working fine in same code but this code is not giving me JSON in code but shows well in Browser.

Comment: alert(jQuery().jquery); shows: 1.12.4 and website: https://products.softsolutionslimited.com

Comment: I gave up and used another service: https://ipapi.co/json/ This URL is working fine and giving me correct result in both console and code. Thanks guys for all your support.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the ajax call is failed, you could check it by using the `.fail()` error handler : https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6v7xcp/

Comment: I gave up and used another service: https://ipapi.co/json/ This URL is working fine and giving me correct result in both console and code. Thanks guys for all your support.